# Redirect url not working in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have a simple search form. After submitting search button url goes to `example.com/search.php?q=query`. I want this to be redirected to `example.com/search/query`.

I have tried

```
RewriteRule search\.php?q=(.*)$ /search/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule search/(.*)$ search.php?q=$1 [NC]
```

But its not working.

Here is my latest try
`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=(.*)$`
`RewriteRule ^search\.php$ http://example.com/search/%1 [R=302,L]`
It is redirecting to `example.com/search/query?q=query`

Comment: No. I am having different problem. What I have tried seems to be correct. But still not working.

Comment: Please be more specific than "it's not working". What error are you getting?